# App running on Xcode simulator but showing error when connecting my phone

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode

I can't run the app on my iPhone XR but the same app is running perfectly in the simulator with no error.
These are the errors that Xcode is showing when trying to run on my phone. The app name is **HelloWorld**.

```
Showing Recent Errors Only
Failed to register bundle identifier. The app identifier "test.HelloWorld" cannot be registered to your development team because it is not available. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.

Showing Recent Messages
No profiles for 'test.HelloWorld' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'test.HelloWorld'.
```

I haven't done anything related to the above mentioned "development team settings". How do I go about this issue?

Comment: You should correct provisioning profile, And then add your device on that then after it will be prepared for running in your device. Please read the article on how to run an IOS application in the device via Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your bundle identifier in your project settings Click on your project > select your target > General > Bundle Identifier. Each app has a unique bundle identifier that identifies their app from other apps. The bundle id you are using right now has already been taken by someone else. Real devices require a Provisioning profile, and a provisioning profile will be automatically made for you if you have the right bundle ID. The convention for Bundle IDs is com.yournameorcompany.yourappname

[image: screeschot]

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. Now it's working just as good as it was on the simulator.